# How to make ZFW2 REST Server

Tags: rest, zend-framework, zend-framework2

Thanx for reading, I'm new to zend and working on ZFW 2, I'm trying to make zend REST sever but couldn't find REST class so tried by json class so in my controller this code:clas

```
<?php
    use Application\Model\Service;
    use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractRestfulController;
    use Zend\View\Model\JsonModel;
    use Zend\Json\Server;
    RestController extends AbstractRestfulController
    {
        public function indexAction()
        {
            $server = new \Zend\Json\Server\Server(); //$service = new Service();
            $service = new Service();
            $server->setClass($service);
            $server->handle();
            exit();
        }
    }
```

and in modules I have this model:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Model;
class Service
{
public function test()
    {
        return('DONE');
    }

}
```

but I don't know if this is Enough and don't know how to make a test for my code .. any help or idea will be appreciated..and thanx in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inventing the wheel, I should use an existing solution. There is a good module for this task: [Phly Restfully](https://github.com/phly/PhlyRestfully). You need to read a [manual](https://phlyrestfully.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

The author, Matthew Weier o'Phinney himself, has a good [introduction into the subject](http://mwop.net/blog/2013-02-11-restful-apis-with-zf2-part-1.html).

Comment: Wouldn't `apigility` be the way to go now` -> http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/investigating-apigility/

Comment: If you think it is, simply add your answer.

Comment: I don't know if it is, which is why my comment is framed as a question.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most current thinking coming from the Zend core team: http://www.apigility.org/